# How to use a column filled with floats in the function Point(lat=float,lon=float) of meteostat? Python

Tags: python, weather

I am trying to build a dataframe using *Daily*(*Point*(lat,lon), start-date, end-date), a function of the **meteostat library** that returns all the daily weather statistics for the location indicated by **Point(lat,lon)** using latitude and longitude, from the start-date to the end-date.

The issue is that *(lat, lon)* arguments needs to be ***float*** and so indicates only one location. I want to addres **several locations** and collect the daily metereological data for each of them.

```py
import meteostat
from datetime import datetime
from meteostat import Point, Daily
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from meteostat import Stations
import pandas as pd
import numpy 

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\leoac\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Python apps\Correlation temp-goals in Serie A\seasons 09-19.csv', ";")
date_not_converted = data['Date']
date_being_converted = datetime.strptime(date_not_converted,'%d,%m,%Y')             #1bis non può essere una serie...allora provo a cambiare il tipo di dati
date = date_being_converted.strftime('%Y,%m,%d')

#plot = Daily(Point(data['lat'][15],data['lon'][15]),d1,d2).fetch()
data['temp']  = Daily(Point(data['lat'][1],data['lon'][1]),datetime(date),datetime(date)).fetch() #1 sistemare il formato data
print(data['temp'])                                                                               #2 trovare un modo per inserire i vettori date e lat/lon nel df
data['temp'].plot(y=['tavg'])
plt.show()

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution inspired by [this github issue](https://github.com/meteostat/meteostat-python/issues/40#issuecomment-879364500). It makes parallel requests for the different locations and then merges the results in a pandas dataframe.

```
from datetime import datetime
from meteostat import Point, Daily
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import pandas as pd

def get_bulk_data(row):
    location = Point(row.lat, row.lon)
    data = Daily(location, row.Date, row.Date).fetch()
    data["latitude"] = row.lat
    data["longitude"] = row.lon
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_csv("seasons.csv", sep=";")
    df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%d,%m,%Y")

    executor = Parallel(n_jobs=cpu_count(), backend='multiprocessing')
    tasks = (
        delayed(get_bulk_data)(row)
        for _, row in df.iterrows()
    )
    list_of_locations_data = executor(tasks)
    data_full = pd.concat(list_of_locations_data)
    print(data_full)
```

It works with the following csv and date formats, you can adapt the code if yours are slightly different:

```
Date;lat;lon
18,02,1997;50.3;-4.7
12,07,1998;41.3;1.5
```

Comment: The executor(tasks) command return this error: 

"RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable."

Comment: I updated the code, do you still have the issue @LeonardoAcquaroli ?

Comment: You can also remove the multiprocessing and do it sequentially.

Comment: Yes! The multiprocessing works fine. Now the problem is that the datetime() function does not recognize my list of strings (well formatted as Y,m,d) as integers separated by a comma.
Any hint?

Comment: Do you have a different date for each location?

Comment: Yes, I explain it.
I'm trying to find the correlation between **temperature** and the **goals** scored in each of the last 10 years' matches of Serie A (Italian soccer).
I created a df comprising the columns 
"date of matchday"  "goals"  "pitch's latitude" "pitch's longitude".
I tried your method @Pierre and it's fine but:
1) **datetime** can't recognize the strings (well formatted as Y,m,d) as int separated by a comma.
2) **Daily** seems to not accept series for the _start_ and _end_ parameters ("date of matchday" should go in _start_ and _end_ parameters).

Comment: I think you should be able to parse the date column directly with pandas. I updated the code to iterate through the pandas dataframe after parsing the column @LeonardoAcquaroli

Comment: You are my sweetheart! I'm sorry still can't cast a vote cause i'm 13 reputation but You really save my work and tought me a lot of things! GG <3